# C++ on Visual Studio 2010: Cannot assign string to a string (mixed types are not supported)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, assign, managed

I'm trying to do something very simple... declare a string in a class, and then assign it to the value of another string defined in a class constructor.

I am using a managed wrapper for an unmanaged class "Unmanaged" *(using a managed wrapper because I want to use it in a C# program, and something I am using is unmanaged and its .sln file is not under my control)*

As you can see, I tried including as many string headers as possible.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using std::string;

namespace UnmanagedWrap {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    public:
        Unmanaged *pu; //pointer to the Unmanaged class
        //the constructor will allocate the pointer pu
        int a;
        int b;
        std::string filePath; //try CString() when get back
        Class1(int a_In, int b_In, std::string filePath_In) : pu(new Unmanaged()) { //constructor
            a = a_In;
            b = b_In;
            filePath = filePath_In; //trying to assign filePath to the inputted filePath_In.......
            }; //end of constructor
```

This is giving me 2 errors:

The first relates to the line `std::string filePath;`

```
1>c:\users\ngrace\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\unmanagedwrap\unmanagedwrap\UnmanagedWrap.h(21): error C4368: cannot define 'filePath' as a member of managed 'UnmanagedWrap::Class1': mixed types are not supported
```

The second relates to the line `filePath = filePath_In;`

```
1>c:\users\ngrace\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\unmanagedwrap\unmanagedwrap\UnmanagedWrap.h(25): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I am very lost as I have spent hours searching for an answer...

Some pages I have gone to for help:

[Including headers from an unmanaged C++ code inside C++/CLI code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302784/including-headers-from-an-unmanaged-c-code-inside-c-cli-code)

[Mixed types are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490098/mixed-types-are-not-supported)

(I would post more but I need reputation of at least 10 to do so....)

Any ideas on why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: The [Mixed types are not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490098/mixed-types-are-not-supported) seems to say it all: `std::string` is not a managed type, so cannot be put in the managed heap.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that would make sense. Do you know if C++ has a managed type for string-like variables?

Answer (score 1):

Using information from Bo Persson and user2666293, I was led to try something, which ended up being an answer to this.

You must use **System::String^** type for managed strings. If using a **managed** string and passing it to a method in an **unmanaged** class, it must be converted to an **unmanaged** string type!

Let's say we're using the unmanaged string type **std::string** in the **unmanaged** class.

The conversion from **System::String^** to **std:string** must be done using:

```
 auto unmannedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
```

and with a header file reference at the top of:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

where **managedString** is of type System::String^

:)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm coming from the gcc world to VC++, and I must say that I hate it.  I ended up changing my std::string class var to a System::String^ and it all works now.  Your answer should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699870.aspx says under bullet 2 that ref classes can only have standard c++ types if they are not public. Try using a regular class or making filePath private.

edit:
I'm not familiar with managed classes but you might try Platform::string instead of std::string : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755812.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699879.aspx
says to use platform strings when you pass strings back and forth to methods in Windows Runtime classes, or when you are interacting with other Windows Runtime components

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will definitely look into these!